# How to tackle these trig questions correctly

Tags: trigonometry

$ \sin(2x) \cdot \cos(2x) + \sin(2x) = 0 $

In the correction model I have something I don't understand is done in the first step:

$ \sin 2x(\cos 2x + 1) = 0 $

Is this step correct? And can someone explain that step to me?

Answer (score 2):

That step is correct, and is performed by taking $\sin 2x$ out as a common factor. In general,
$$ab + a = a(b+1)$$
for any numbers $a,b$.

The usual error made in these questions is to act upon the temptation to *divide* by $\sin 2x$, in which case you obtain all the solutions corresponding to $\cos 2x = -1$, but miss out all the solutions corresponding to $\sin 2x = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about it but for some reason I didn't understand it.. thanks!